# Какой месяц переводится как «солнечный, теплый»?

Tags: иностранные-слова

Название какого месяца в переводе буквально означает «солнечный, теплый»?

Comment: Огласите весь список месяцев!

Comment: все месяцы в году

Answer (score 2):

> Название какого месяца в переводе буквально означает «солнечный, теплый»?

Строго говоря, никакой месяц не подходит, по моему скромному мнению.

Если хотите, **elena_perstneva-plotnikova**, то напишите подробнее. Откуда возник такой вопрос? Возможно, тогда будет проще на него ответить.

В современном русском языке используются названия месяцев латинского происхождения (немного по-другому теперь произносящиеся). Латынь я немного изучал. В другой аналогичной теме написали о месяце *апреле*. Это единственный месяц, по-моему, название которого хоть немного подходит. Но с большой натяжкой. Если допустить, что название апрель -- лат. *Aprilis* -- происходит от лат. слова *apricus*, что значит солнечный, имеющий много солнечного света, согреваемый солнцем.

НО! Слабым местом такой версии мне кажется, что слово *apricus* из так называемой вульгарной латыни, т.е. это просторечие, разговорный вариант. И возможно из поздней латыни, времён распада империи. Происходит от глагола *aperire* -- открывать. В классическом  варианте *Aprilis*, т.е. апрель -- это скорее что-то связанное с открытием, т.к. это **более старое**, **исходное** значение. То что открытое место в жаркой Италии у римлян ассоциируется с солнечным и тёплым, это уже вторично, я думаю. Тепло у них, южные края, не Чукотка! Там, на Севере, на открытом месте не очень согреешься. :-)

- - 

Если задуматься о том, что у русских не всегда были латинские названия месяцев, и поискать славянские наименования, то и тут ничего подходящего, на мой взгляд, нет. Возьмём родственные, близкие русскому яз., славянские языки. Я знаю названия месяцев со славянскими корнями на украинском, польском и хорватском языках. Ничего похожего не нахожу: листопад, травань/травень, коловоз (возле воза, значит), березень...

Comment: Давайте остановимся на апреле! В апреле мужик сопрел, растаскивая навоз по огороду.

Comment: Смотря какая цель вопроса.Nikolja прав, с научной точки зрения - никакой.А если пофантазировать в духе народной этимологии - то ИЮЛЬ: Илий-Юрий-Ярий-Ярила- солнце.

Comment: Да просто исходя из нормальной логики - июль самый жаркий месяц!)

Comment: Вопрос о **переводе**. Какой Ярило?  
Скорее всего - с какой-то олимпиады или чего-то подобного.
Наверняка автор вопроса (настоящий) не вдавался в детали. 
Так что Апрель подходит более всего. Хотя, согласен, бредовато слегка.

А может это вообще не про русские названия, а?

Comment: >А может это вообще не про русские названия, а?

Верно, напрашивается такой вопрос. И я думал об этом.

Но тогда, если не русские названия, то какие? Хотел бы я от автора вопроса услышать ответ.

Сейчас, наверное, **в большинстве** стран Европы используют **латинские** названия, от Великобритании до Сербии. Особенности местн. произношения, в данном случае, роли не играют (англ. мэй или русс. май). Их мы уже рассмотрели (может быть, я что-то упустил?).

Славянск. названия месяцев? Украина, Беларусь, кое-кто из других славян.

Кто ещё использует не лат. названия, допустим, из бывшего соц.лагеря

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2
Я смотрел. Из славян на латинские перешли только мы, чехи и сербы. 
Но дело в том, что в  славянских названиях солнце не фигурирует вообще.